# Aligning paragraph with floated element

Tags: css, css-float

Is there a precise way to get the top and left sides of the paragraph flowing around the floated img to align. When I zoom in and use developer tools they are not perfectly aligned but very close.

http://codepen.io/BennyHH/pen/mPBEvG

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .contain {
      width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: silver;
    }
    .box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background: blue;
      float: left;
      margin: 15px 15px 0;
    }
    p {
      padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<section class="contain">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
</section>
```

Comment: It *can* be done, but as every character takes different space inside a paragraph, it's strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

It can work like that.

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .contain {
      width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: silver;
    }
    .box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background: blue;
      float: left;
      margin: 15px 15px 0;
    }
    p {
      padding: 15px;
      width: calc(100% - 215px);
      margin-left: 215px;
    }
```

```html
<section class="contain">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put `overflow:hidden` on `<p>` tag

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contain {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: silver;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 0;
}

p {
  padding: 13px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*   text-align: justify; */
}
```

```html
<section class="contain">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
</section>
```